# PostgreSQL + MeCab 全文検索での単語区切りについて

Tags: postgresql, mecab

PostgreSQL + MeCab の全文検索でデータベースのフィールドを検索しようとしています。そこで、あることに気がつきました。

- `大阪市生野区` を `大阪` で検索するとヒットします。
- `大阪市生野区` を `大阪市` で検索するとヒットしません。

実験した SQL とその結果です。

```
dd=> select to_tsquery('大阪') @@ to_tsvector('japanese'::regconfig, '大阪市生野区');
 ?column?
----------
 t
(1 行)


dd=> select to_tsquery('大阪市') @@ to_tsvector('japanese'::regconfig, '大阪市生野区');
 ?column?
----------
 f
(1 行)


dd=> select ja_wakachi('大阪市生野区');
   ja_wakachi
-----------------
 大阪 市 生野 区
(1 行)
```

MeCab が 大阪市生野区 を `大阪` + `市` + `生野` + `区` と単語を分解するので `大阪市` ではヒットしないのだと思いますが…

この点を考慮するための技術的な方策は存在しますでしょうか。

Comment: 質問の内容を実現しようと思うと、単語を分割する時に複数の分割単位が必要になると思われます。形態素解析器 「Sudachi」はそれができるようなので試してみませんか？次の記事は、Elasticsearch 用です。https://qiita.com/sorami/items/99604ef105f13d2d472b

Comment: @YasuhiroNiji  Sudachi ですかー 初めて知りました。ポスグレ界隈の情報しか調べていなかったので… 勉強になります。試してみます。ありがとうございます!